# grep positive/negative integer value only

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

I am looking to grep any positive/negative integers only and no decimals, or any other variation including a number.

I have a testpart1.txt which has:

```
This is a test for Part 1
Lets write -1324
Amount: $42.27
Numbers:
       -345,64
067

Phone numbers:

       (111)222-2424
```

This should output the following code:

```
This is a test for Part 1
Lets write -1324
067
```

I am new to bash and I cannot find how to exclude any number separated with a character like a '.' or ','. I am able to get all the numbers with the following code but I am stuck after that:

```
egrep '[0-9]' testpart1.txt
```

This gives me the opposite of what I want:

```
grep '[0-9]\.[0-9]' testpart1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
grep -E '(^|[[:blank:]])[+-]?[0-9]+([[:blank:]]|$)' file
```

```
This is a test for Part 1
Lets write -1324
067
```

**Details:**

- `-E`: Enables extended regex matching
- `(^|[[:blank:]])`: Match line start or a space or a tab character
- `[+-]?`: Match optional `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]+`: Match 1 or more digits
- `([[:blank:]]|$)`: Match line end or a space or a tab character